# post method in laravel give MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel

post method in Laravel give MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Html code

```
<form action="newslatter" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>
<input type="email"name="email">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit">
```

and controller code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class newsletter extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
{
 return $request -> name .'   '. $request -> email;
}
```

and Route

```
Route::POST('Newslatter','newsletter@store');
```

What problems are my codes?

err pic

[image: screenshot from err]

Answer (score 6):

Change `Newslatter` to `newslatter` in the route to make it work:

```
Route::post('newslatter', 'newsletter@store');
```

Also, add [CSRF field](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-introduction) to the form:

```
<form action="newslatter" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

In [Laravel 5.6+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf):

```
<form action="newslatter" method="post">
    @csrf
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this problem occurs because of

```
<form action="newslatter" method="post">
```

Please try as

```
<form action="{{ route('route-name') }}"> metho="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

And

```
Route::post('/newslatter', 'ControllerName@methodName')->name('route-name');
```

Comment: Would you please see in the URL. Why it has shown as // before newslatter 
https://ibb.co/b9d6Y7

Comment: I create this sample project for you... https://github.com/FierceBengalTiger/stackOverflow-newslatter

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use laravel recipes they are cool

```
{{ Form::model($role, array('route' => array('roles.update', $role->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>"form-horizontal form-label-left","novalidate"=>'true')) }}
```

declares a form passing the $roles variable from the backend and generates the csrf_field for you(solving the above problem).

also within the form

```
{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12','required'=>'required','id'=>"name")) }}
```

to display the name property in the passed $user object(avoiding lenghty empty condition checks on your html)