# Why is Post method giving the error MethodNotAllowedHttpException in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to submit a form in Laravel but I am getting the error **The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.**

I have tried the suggestions in [post method in laravel give MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719360/post-method-in-laravel-give-methodnotallowedhttpexception) but none is working.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="row" style="background: #ffffff;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="background: white; margin: 10px">
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('companies.update',[$company->id]) }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}

      <input type="hidden" name="method" value="put">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company.name">Name <span class="required">*</span> </label>
        <input placeholder="Enter name" id="company-name" required name="description" spellcheck="false" class="form-control" value="{{ $company->name }}" />


      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company-content">Description</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Enter Description" style="resize: vertical" id="company-content" name="description" rows="5" spellcheck="true" class="form-control autosize-target text-left">
                                {{$company->description}}</textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Replacing post with **get**,**put** removes the error but not doing what I want.

These are my routes

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('companies','CompaniesController');
Route::resource('projects','ProjectsController');
Route::resource('roles','RolesController');
Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

In the CompaniesController I have

```
 public function update(Request $request, Company $company)
    {

        $companyupdates = Company::where('id', $company->id)->update([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
        ]);

        if($companyupdates){
            return redirect()->route('companies.show', ['company'=>$company->id])->with('success','Company Updated Successfully');
        }
        return back()->withInput();
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Show you're routes file, please.

Comment: I dont' know if this is causing the issue, but i think your should change your method input to "_method" as described in the laravel form method spoofing, or use the blade directive ```@method('PUT')```

Comment: ^ we need to see your routes.

Comment: There's a bit of inconsistency between `<form method="post" ...` and `<input type="hidden" name="method" value="put">`; I think you just need to pick one or the other and make sure your route supports whichever your choose.

Comment: Post full routes such as `Route::post('payment/notify', ['uses' => 'PurchaseController@paymentNotify', 'as' => 'payment.notify']);`

Comment: @Kamal `Route::resource()` is shorthand for a bunch of routes connected to a `ResourceController`; those **are** the full routes.

Comment: For resources, `update` can use PUT or PATCH, not POST, so see the answer below. Here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the blade directives instead:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('companies.update',$company->id) }}">
      @csrf
      @method('PUT')
```

**Note**: you don't need to pass the company id with '[ ]'

In this input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="put">
```

The name should be `_method` according to the laravel form method spoofing

Example from the docs:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

With the blade directives:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>`
```

**Why is this error occurring?**

You put the wrong name on your method input, so laravel will recognize this form action as POST, and not PUT. Since it's a update action, laravel will thrown this error.

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or  DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

For more info: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing)